# Consume webservice returning Complex objects in Coldfusion

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

We are using the [Argus WS](http://www.argusmedia.com/ArgusWSVSTO/ArgusOnline.asmx) and I'm stuck at figuring out how to consume the `GetUpdatedPricesInDateTimeRange` method.

It returns a complex object type and I'm unable to access the element structure within the returned object.

Getting the error

```
Element <e.g. element name> is undefined in a Java object of type class org.tempuri.GetUpdatedPricesInDateTimeRangeResponseGetUpdatedPricesInDateTimeRangeResult.
```

Webservice is being invoked as follows:

```
<cfinvoke  
webservice="http://www.argusmedia.com/ArgusWSVSTO/ArgusOnline.asmx?wsdl"
method="GetUpdatedPricesInDateTimeRange" 
returnvariable="PricesResponse"> 
  <cfinvokeargument name="authToken" value="#AuthToken#"/>
  <cfinvokeargument name="fromDateTime" value="2017-03-01"/>
  <cfinvokeargument name="toDateTime" value="2017-03-02"/>
  <cfinvokeargument name="startId" value="0"/>
</cfinvoke>
```

Any pointers would be really helpful.

**Edit 1**: CFDump return variable
[image: CFdump]

**Edit 2**: Based on Leigh's suggestion, this is what worked for me.

**XML**

```
PricesResponse.get_any()[2].getAsString()
```

The XML had namespaces in it, hence XML Search worked as follows:

```
XmlSearch(XMLDoc,"//*[local-name()='Element_Name']")
```

Comment: Does the invoke return a variable named returnvariable?  If so, can you dump it?

Comment: @DanBracuk : added the cfdump.

Comment: This is a SOAP-webservice right? have you tried generating a request with eg. soapUI?

Comment: @GauravS - Continue invoking the methods and dumping the results. For example, what do you get when you dump `get_any()`? Looks like it returns an array of elements.

Comment: @Leigh : `PricesResponse.get_any()[2].getAsString()` gave me the XML I was after. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Leigh's comment, `get_any()` method of the `returnvariable` can be used to get the underlying XML.

Dump of `get_any()` returns the array of Message Elements.

[image: MessageElement]

`getAsString()` method of `get_any()` returns the expected XML string.

```
<cfdump var="#PricesResponse.get_any()[1].getAsString()#">
```

**Note** : The intended XML can be in either of the MessageElement[] array element and not in the first one.

**Note 2** : XMLSearch with namespaces in the XML worked as follows:

```
XmlSearch(XMLDoc,"//*[local-name()='Element_Name']")
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the resolution. Just to clarify, when you say "either of the elements"  do you mean *all* of the elements contain relevant XML - or only one of them? (I am not familiar with the API).

Comment: @Leigh : The returned object had the relevant XML with data only in the 2nd element. The 1st element just had the schema definition. This can be different for other APIs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying as that is definitely not what I would have expected.